# Login to power bi service online (silently i.e. without the popup) using powershell

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I would like to login to Power BI Online service and remove rows from a dataset using the REST API. I have the rest of the code going fine but the login seems to not work. This is what I tried. Can someone help me please? Thank you!

```
$pbiUsername = "abc.xyz@xxx.com"
$pbiPassword = "Password"
$clientId = "a81b2cc1-4c97-2323-bal4-eeb21c4c6e46"

$body = @{"resource" = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"
    "client_id" = $clientId;
    "grant_type" = "password";
    "username" = $pbiUsername;
    "password" = $pbiPassword;
    "scope" = "openid"
}

$authUrl = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token/"
$authResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $authUrl –Method POST -Body $body

$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    "Authorization" = $authResponse.token_type + " " + 
                      $authResponse.access_token
}

$restURL = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups"
$restResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $restURL –Method GET -Headers $headers
```

Comment: Can you explain in what way " the login seems to not work". Do you get an error?

Answer (score 3):

"Login doesn't seems to work" doesn't give us enough information to hint you what is the problem.

I will recommend you to use the official [Microsoft Power BI Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps) to do tasks like this. It has big advantage - you don't need to register an application to use it. Here is how your code would look like in this case:

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile

$password = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "abc.xyz@xxx.com" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'groups/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/datasets/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/tables/xxxxxx/rows' -Method Delete

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I could login but I get this error. Any idea how to tackle this? Thanks!

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod : One or more errors occurred.
At line:31 char:1
+ Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'groups/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...werBIRestMethod:InvokePowerBIRestMethod) [Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : One or more errors occurred.,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Profile.InvokePowerBIRestMethod

Comment: The error text doesn't give much information, but from the source you pasted, I still see the `x`-es. Didn't you replaced them with **actual** groupId and datasetId values?!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I replaced the x-es with actual groupId and datasetId but got the error. Any idea on how I should proceed from here? Thank you for guiding me. Much appreciated.

Comment: The PowerShell error simply [doesn't give enough information](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2193) to allow diagnosing the issue. You need to surround this call with `try..catch` and collect more information, like status code and response content.

Comment: Hi Andrey, how do you do this without having your password saved in this file as plain text?

Comment: @PapaSheng By using Azure Vault for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell

Answer (score 1):

Since PowerBI now has enabled the **[Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-service-principal)**, you don't need to worry about the username and password and more importantly, you **DON'T NEED PRO Licenses**

using the Service Principal you can now able to log in without popup as well as username, password

```
$applicationId = "xxxxxxxx";
$securePassword = "xxxxxx" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $securePassword
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId "xxxx"
```

Comment: The SPN cannot administrate the gateway settings...

Comment: It has but with some limitations see [my blog](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Data-Gateway-Automation-using-PowerShell-Part-1/ba-p/1117330)

Answer (score 0):

The error is not handled with try catch - you still get the same error with this:
try {Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount} catch {"Boo"}

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30080599)

Answer (score 0):

I follow the steps to fix this issue.

**RESOLUTION**
To resolve this issue, we need to install the correct module.  It may not be the latest build, but the builds have to match in order for things to work for us.  In my scenario, I installed the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Workspaces 1.0.830 so that it matched the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile.

I went to the PowerShell Gallery to get the Install-Module cmd.
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt/1.0.326

1. From an Administrative Command-Prompt, type Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Workspaces -RequiredVersion 1.0.830

NOTE: Remember, for my lab scenario, I used the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Workspaces Module.  You will need to install the module that you are focused.

2. Once installed, close all PowerShell Windows or open a brand new PowerShell window and then type Get-Module.  Now the installed modules should match.

**NOTE: You have to start a new PowerShell session.  If you don’t the error may not go away.**

https://dastrongman.wordpress.com/2020/01/11/pbiwiki-login-with-the-power-bi-service-account/